# Good textbooks for lattice and coding theory

Tags: reference-request, algebraic-geometry, coding-theory, integer-lattices

I am looking for good textbooks for lattice and coding theory. Lattice and coding theory are very interesting on their own, but I have application of the theory to K3 surfaces & modular forms (and vice versa) in mind.

My goal is probably to go through Conway & Slone's "Sphere Packings, Lattices and Groups" but the book is too difficult for me at this point (the book is a collection of research papers). I have read roughly half of Ebeling's "Lattices and Codes", but it is getting harder and harder.

I would appreciate it if someone could introduce good textbooks to me. Expository articles are also welcome.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I learned coding theory from the following texts (but I have to admit I didn't learn anything about lattices from them):

1. This is a pretty good introduction (that I had when I was learning): [Hoffman, et al.](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0824786114)
2. [Pless & Huffman](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0521131707) has almost anything you could want about codes.
3. [Roman](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0387978127) has much more on information theory
4. [Blahut](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0521556597) is targeted more at engineers, I think.

Comment: Thank you for introducing me the books. Coding theory is itself intriguing.