# A book in coding theory.

Tags: reference-request, coding-theory

I want to study coding theory, but I don't know any text book about. Can anyone indicate to me some book? I'm in the last year of undergraduate mathematics course, so I would of a basic book, but that provides to me an experience in this field.

Comment: Searching for questions tagged [coding-theory+reference-request](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/coding-theory+reference-request) yields two questions, which seem related (but not identical): [Cryptography and Coding Theory](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/253043/cryptography-and-coding-theory) and
[Good textbooks for lattice and coding theory](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/205351/good-textbooks-for-lattice-and-coding-theory).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Books**

Peruse them online and see if they agree with you, they are not in any particular order and I may have missed a couple.

- A First Course in Coding Theory by Raymond Hill
- Information and Coding Theory  by Gareth A. Jones and J.Mary Jones
- Introduction to Coding and Information Theory by Steven Roman
- Introduction to Coding Theory by Ron Roth
- Introduction to Coding Theory by Juergen Bierbrauer
- Coding Theory: A First Course by San Ling and Chaoping Xing
- Introduction to Coding Theory by Van Lint, J. H.
- Coding Theory and Cryptography: The Essentials, Second Edition by D.C. Hankerson, Gary Hoffman, D.A. Leonard and Charles C. Lindner

Note: there are also graduate level books in this area.

**Open Courseware**

- [MIT OCW CT](http://ocw.mit.edu/courses/electrical-engineering-and-computer-science/6-895-essential-coding-theory-fall-2004/syllabus/)
- Check the [*OCW Consortium*](http://www.ocwconsortium.org/ko/courses/catalog/catalog/1)

**Other Potential Sources**

- Try your local college library and see if you find others that suit you and your needs
- Search for introductory course materials and notes online

Comment: All those resources deserve a TU!

Comment: It would be better to split this answer into individual books, to enable individual up- and downvotes.

Answer (score 1):

Another nice resource which IIRC has a decent amount of coding theory is the excellent *Information Theory, Inference, and Learning Algorithms* by David MacKay. It's a published book but it is also available online at http://www.inference.phy.cam.ac.uk/itila/book.html

Comment: It should be noted that this book does only graph-based codes, not algebraic constructions. It is a nice book which hodge podges a bunch of topics at a high level.

Answer (score 0):

A little gem which is missing so far:

Simeon Ball: *A Course in Algebraic Error-Correcting Codes*. Birkhäuser/Springer 2020. [link](https://link.springer.com/book/10.1007/978-3-030-41153-4)

Answer (score 0):

A pretty good and comprehensive textbook which has not been mentioned in the other answers:

W. Cary Huffman and Vera Pless: *Fundamentals of Error-Correcting Codes*. Cambridge University Press 2003. [link](https://doi.org/10.1017/CBO9780511807077)